# box2d body moves differently according to world width/height units

Tags: libgdx

I've got the following settings:

```java
private static final float SCENE_WIDTH = 1280; 
private static final float SCENE_HEIGHT =720;

//Gravity
world = new World(new Vector2(0,-9.8f), true);

camera = new OrthographicCamera();
viewport = new FitViewport(SCENE_WIDTH, SCENE_HEIGHT, camera);
//viewport.apply();
camera.position.set(SCENE_WIDTH * 0.5f, SCENE_HEIGHT * 0.5f, 0);
```

And then I create a body with the following features:

```java
//Center the body so it can start falling down
defaultDynamicBodyDef.position.x = SCENE_WIDTH * 0.5f;
defaultDynamicBodyDef.position.y = SCENE_HEIGHT * 0.5f;

// Shape for square
square = new PolygonShape();
// IMPORTANT 100 = 1m
square.setAsBox(100, 100);

// Fixture definition for our shapes
boxFixtureDef = new FixtureDef();
boxFixtureDef.shape = square;
boxFixtureDef.density = 0.8f;
boxFixtureDef.friction = 0.8f;
boxFixtureDef.restitution = 0.15f;
```

See above where it says `IMPORTANT`. With these settings when `1m = 100` scaling the square falls down slowly.

But if my settings are like:

```java
private static final float SCENE_WIDTH = 12.8f; 
private static final float SCENE_HEIGHT =7.2f;
```

and then change the square size to:

```java
// Shape for square
square = new PolygonShape();
// IMPORTANT 1m = 1
square.setAsBox(1f, 1f);
```

the square falls down much faster? I am confused. So to sum up, having world units 1280 and 720 with the square parameters 100 and 100 the body falls slower than world units of 12.8 and 7.2 and 1 & 1 for the squre. In both cases I use world units but the speed of fall is different? Why is that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because the gravity is the same in both examples. So the square's will move at the same speed/acceleration and with the smaller viewport in the second example the square will be faster out of screen.